# Placeholder in Angular on IE issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, placeholder

I have a custom input directive which adds each new element as a tag to a list of previously entered items. And my code works fine in all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge), my issue is with IE11 and lower. I can't seem to clear off placeholder text, once the input fields are selected.

I'm not quite sure what to do..or how to modify so it behaves nicely in IE also.

main.html

```
<tagged disabled="{{ canNotEdit }" property="newProfile.educationSubjects" placeholder="{{ 'newVacancy.educationFieldsPlaceholder' | translate }}">
</tagged>
```

tagged.html

```
<div ng-class="{'element-disabled': disabled }" class="position-relative">
    <div class="position-relative">
        <input type="text"
               ng-disabled="{{ disabled }}"
               class="inpt"
               placeholder="{{ placeholder }}">
        <span class="caret">
            <svg class="caret-icon">
                <use xlink:href="images/svg-generated/svg/symbols.svg#add-s">
                </use>
            </svg>
        </span>

        <div>
            <div class="taglist list-inline">
                <ul>
                    <li class="tag"
                        ng-click="removeItem($index)"
                        ng-repeat="item in dataArray track by $index">
                        {{ item }}
                        <svg class="tag-close">
                            <use xlink:href="images/svg-generated/svg/symbols.svg#remove"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my directive controller:

tagged-dir.js

```
'use strict';

export default function() {
  return {

    restrict: 'E',

    scope: {
      dataArray: '=property',
      disabled: '@',
      placeholder: '@'
    },

    templateUrl: '..path-to/tagged.html',

    link: function(scope, element) {

      var input = angular.element(element.find('input')[0]);
      var button = angular.element(element.find('span')[0]);

      scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        if(scope.disabled === 'true') {
          return false;
        }
        scope.dataArray.splice(index, 1);
      };

      function addTag() {

        let val = input.val().replace(/\/|\\/g, '');

        if(!val) {
          return;
        }

        scope.dataArray.push(val);
        scope.$digest();

        input.val('');
      }

      input.bind('keydown keypress', function(event) {
        if(event.which === 13 && scope.disabled !== 'true') {
          event.preventDefault();
          addTag();
        }
      });

      input.bind('mouseenter', function() {
        if(scope.disabled === 'true') {
          return false;
        }
        element.addClass('taglist-hovered');
      });

      input.bind('mouseleave', function() {
        if(scope.disabled === 'true') {
          return false;
        }
        element.removeClass('taglist-hovered');
      });

      input.bind('focus', function() {
        if(scope.disabled === 'true') {
          return false;
        }
        element.addClass('taglist-focused');
      });

      input.bind('blur', function() {
        if(scope.disabled === 'true') {
          return false;
        }
        element.removeClass('taglist-focused');
      });

      button.on('click', function(event) {
        if(scope.disabled === 'true') {
          return false;
        }
        addTag();
      });

    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that the issue was with `disabled` element on the `<tagged>` directive.

IE interprets the `disabled` attribute on the (to him unknown) `tagged` element and also disables all child elements (including the input field).

So what I did was actually renamed the `disabled` element with a custom one, and replace it with new where I needed it.